# I'm making an API rest with node.js, and I'm trying to get the details of an event with passing the id of the event in parameters

Tags: node.js

I'm making an API rest with node.js, and I'm trying to get the details of an event with passing the id of the event in parameters

```
app.get('/evenement/:id', (req, res) => {
    var post_data = req.body;  //Get POST params

    const id = post_data.id_evenement;

    con.query('SELECT * FROM `evenement` WHERE id_evenement =' ,{id},  (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

and I'm getting an error:

> code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
>
> errno: 1064,
>    sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1",
>
> sqlState: '42000',
>
> index: 0,
>
> sql: 'SELECT * FROM `evenement` WHERE id_evenement ='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is a bit off

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM `evenement` WHERE id_evenement =?' ,[id],  (error, result) => {
    if (error) throw error;

    res.send(result);
});
```

Update:
Since you are not getting any data, noticed you are trying to get the id incorrect as well

```
const id = req.params.id;
```

Comment: thank you, the error disappeared , but it's rendering empty json, that's how I test it in postman 'localhost:1337/evenement/1' and the table is not empty

Comment: Check if there is an entry in the database where the id_evenement is equal to what you are passing in as the id.

Comment: worked, thank you :) i just changed 'const id = req.params.id;'

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement is incomplete, try with this (added `?` at the end and `id` in an array of parameters):

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM `evenement` WHERE id_evenement = ?' ,[id],  (error, result) => {
```

You can have a look here to see how to form the query https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/shownodejs_cmd.asp?filename=demo_db_where_placeholder

Comment: thank you, the error disappeared , but its rendering empty json, that s how i test it in postman 'http://localhost:1337/evenement/1'

Comment: and the table is not empty